# Batch loop write text file to different folders

Tags: batch-file

I would like to write a text file into every folder of a directory. The text file should contain the path to the specific folder.

I have tried a loop like this, but it says the folder/ directory syntax is wrong:

```
@ECHO OFF
cd C:\path_to_direcotry
set wd=%CD%
for /D %%a in ("%wd%\*.*") do (
(
ECHO Is this the path to the sub folder?
ECHO "%wd%\%%a"
) > "%%a\path.txt"
)
```

I am new to batch scripts, any help would be appreciated, including pointing out duplicate questions. I did not find any that work.

Comment: Do [`cd`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) **`/D`** `"C:\path_to_directory"` to also change the drive; also check out [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)/[`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) as an alternative to `cd`. There is no need to store `%CD%` into another variable (`wd`), and you do not need to specify it in `for /D` (just use `in ("*.*")`, then use [`~` modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) like `echo %%~fa` to get the full path then, or also `> "%%~fa\path.txt"`)...

Comment: Please post your exact code by cutting and pasting. You have mis-spelt `directory` in `path_to_direcotry` and this may be the root of your problem.

Comment: All you should need is: `@For /D %%A In ("C:\path_to_directory\*")Do @(Echo(%%~fA)>"%%~fA\path.txt"`. _You would replace the `%%~fA` between the two parentheses with the real string you're wanting to use_.

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. Compo, your solution works perfectly, thank you so much! Also thank you aschipfl for explaining how it works!